# OSError when installing ansible with pip in CLI on Windows 10: 'OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Tags: pip, ansible, windows-10, oserror

The entire output message I get, irrespective of whether I do it with `pip` or `pip3`, or in `PowerShell` or `bash`, or with or without `--user`, is:

```
PS C:\Users\user> pip install ansible --user
Collecting ansible
  Using cached ansible-4.0.0.tar.gz (33.3 MB)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i5a881am\\ansible_79b10d1774894f28be88e26c8c0385cb\\ansible_collections/amazon/aws/tests/unit/plugins/modules/placebo_recordings/cloudformation/client_request_token_s3_stack/cloudformation.CreateStack_1.json'
```

Comment: From the [doc on controller node requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#control-node-requirements): `Windows is not supported for the control node, read more about this in [Matt Davis’s blog post](http://blog.rolpdog.com/2020/03/why-no-ansible-controller-for-windows.html)`. You can [install ansible in WSL](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/using-ansible-through-windows-10s-subsystem-linux) though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Zeitounator's comment to my OP, I could finally install `ansible` on `Windows10 WSL` correctly using [this link](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/using-ansible-through-windows-10s-subsystem-linux).

It is essential to stress here that for achieving this one needs to install `bash CLI` (or rather [Windows10 WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)).